# What would be a word that means pushing someone to their limit in a negative form

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

I'm currently writing a story about a young man who was took everything from him and that died for the causes he fought for, I'm looking for a word that means taking everything from someone and more.

Comment: Do you want a word that means pushing someone to their limit, a word that means a victim of theft, or a word that means one who died for his beliefs?

Comment: A word for someone who died for his beliefs is more fitting for what I'm going for.

Comment: I've deleted the 'expressions' tag as it conflicts with your definite single-word request, allowing phrases etc. But 'tragic victim' is what I'd use.